# Chrome and Safari slider overlapping navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index, bxslider

I have a z-index problem in Chrome and Safari only. There seems to be a problem with the bxslider overlapping the navigation. If you hover over produkts and scroll down in Chrome or Safari, the navigation disappears, even though the wrapper around the slider has a z-index set to 1 and is position relative. If I remove the slider everything is working fine.

Here is the link of the website it only occurs on the main page (home).

http://vortexpower.ch/

Comment: Didn't noticed any issue with Chrome 32. Could you show any screenshots?

Comment: just looked in Chrome, FFox, and Safari,and don't see any problem.

Comment: I noticed the problem in Chrome 32. The problem is that the menu dissapears when you scroll untill the slider disappears. It's really curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with id `headwrapper` has an overflow: hidden property. This hides the menu. When disconnected all seems to work.